# awk those value contain blank

Tags: shell, awk

how can I grep those values which are having space in it. I' am  trying :

```
awk -F '\t' '$19 ~ /[0-9[:blank:]0-9]/ {print $19}' myfile.txt
0000280000
0000209600
0000181 96
0000179586
0000122393
0000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

First, the expression `[0-9[:blank:]0-9]` matches the numbers `0-9` **or** a blank. (the second 0-9 is superfluous). This is true for all of your test data in column 19, that's why they all got printed.

If you want to check for a blank - which is a space or a tab character - you can just use:

```
awk -F'\t' '$19 ~ /[[:blank:]]/{print $19}'
```

however, since fields are delimited by tab, you can just use a literal space:

```
awk -F'\t' '$19 ~ / /{print $19}'
```

---

Besides that, checking for a literal space in a field doesn't require a regex in `awk`, you can use `index()`:

```
awk -F'\t' 'index($19, " "){print $19}' myfile.txt
```

`index()` returns zero if field 19 doesn't contain a space, otherwise the position of the first occurrence in the string. Since string indexes start at `1` in `awk` this position will be always greater than zero which evaluates to `true` and makes awk print that field in the following block.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify *POSIX* character class separately, like below:

```
awk -F '\t' '$19~/[0-9]+[[:space:]]/{ print $19 }' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a simple grep statement:

`grep ' ' filename.txt`

For finding space in a particular field, use this:

```
cat file.txt|awk -F '\t' {'print $19'}|grep ' '
```